# Clear html5 canvas, then re-initialize it

Tags: html, canvas, graph, paperjs

I'm working on an activity where a user would draw a line chart and check to see how close it is to an actual chart. I've got it working, but need help on 'resetting' the canvas. I can get it to clear, but I need to reinitialize it after it's cleared so the user can try again.

here is the reset code I have so far:

```
var clearCanvas = false;

function onFrame(event) {
    if (clearCanvas && project.activeLayer.hasChildren()) {
        project.activeLayer.removeChildren();
        clearCanvas = false;
    }
}
$('.clear').on('click', function() {
    clearCanvas = true;
    return false
})
```

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EXXJb/)

I've kinda hacked this code together, as I'm not a coder, so go easy if it's not the best way of doing things. If anyone has a cleaner/more efficient way of doing this I'm all ears!

Thanks in advance. 
S

Answer (score 0):

First, your jsfiddle is getting a 404 when it tries to use "http://paperjs.org/static/js/paper.js".  Switching that to "https://raw.github.com/paperjs/paper.js/master/dist/paper.js" works for me.

Second, if you want the user to try again, they need to be able to place 7 (or however many) new points after the reset, so in your `onFrame` function you need to set `maxPoints` to 0 when clearing the canvas.

Third, the path that connects the users points will need to be re-initialized.  That can be done by calling `path.removeSegments()` and then re-adding `path` to the `activeLayer`.

Fourth, once you have removed the children from the activeLayer, `fullChart` (the "answer") is no longer on the activeLayer.  You will have to re-add it and re-set its opacity to 0 (if you want it hidden again).

Putting those together, this `onFrame` seems to do what you are attempting:

```
function onFrame(event) {
    if (clearCanvas && project.activeLayer.hasChildren()) {
        project.activeLayer.removeChildren();
        fullChart.opacity = 0;
        maxPoints = 0;
        path.removeSegments();
        project.activeLayer.addChildren([fullChart, path]);
        clearCanvas = false;
    }
}
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TNLAg/5/).

---

Other notes:

I don't believe you have to separate your code like that; you could just clear the canvas in your button's callback instead of waiting for the `onFrame`.  So all of the code in `onFrame` could go in the callback instead (just without the `clearCanvas` variable).

I would also recommend using the same `Point` objects for your myCircle and myPath instead of making new ones with the same coordinates.  For example:

```
var point1 = new Point(72, 214);
var point2 = new Point(205, 177);
...
var point7 = new Point(868, 177);
var myCircle1 = new Path.Circle(point1, 10)
var myCircle2 = new Path.Circle(point2, 10)
....
var myCircle7 = new Path.Circle(point7, 10)
var myPath = new Path([point1, point2, ..., point7]);
```